# Is ''after having a baby'' dangling participle or verbal noun?

Tags: dangling-participle

> Exercise is the only way to get a flat stomach after having a baby.

This sentence is from the Oxford Advanced Learner Dictionary.

Is ''after having a baby'' dangling participle or subjectless verbal noun?

Comment: Technically, yes, but in reality no. The gerund-participial clause "having a baby" doesn't have a subject, but it is understood as if it does, even if the subject may be understood to be "some arbitrary person".

Comment: It's governed by the preposition "after", so it must be a NP, and there is no participle.